# Get video dimension in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video

I can get size of image, like this:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('my_image.jpg',0)
height, width = img.shape[:2]
```

How about video?

Comment: you get one frame from video and you have image so you can use `shape`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It gives `width` and `height` of file or camera as `float` (so you may have to convert to `integer`)

But it always gives me `0.0 FPS`.

```
import cv2

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi') # 0=camera
 
if vcap.isOpened(): 
    # get vcap property 
    width  = vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float `width`
    height = vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float `height`
    # or
    width  = vcap.get(3)  # float `width`
    height = vcap.get(4)  # float `height`

    # it gives me 0.0 :/
    fps = vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

---

It seems it can works `fps = vcap.get(7)` but I checked this only on one file.

---

**EDIT 2019:** Currently `cv2` uses little different names

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH   # 3
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT  # 4

cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS           # 5
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT   # 7
```

but they have the same values: `3`, `4`, `5`, `7`

```
import cv2

#vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # built-in webcamera

vcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

if vcap.isOpened(): 
    width  = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float `width`
    height = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float `height`
    # or
    width  = vcap.get(3)  # float `width`
    height = vcap.get(4)  # float `height`

    print('width, height:', width, height)
    
    fps = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    # or
    fps = vcap.get(5)
    
    print('fps:', fps)  # float `fps`
    
    frame_count = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    # or
    frame_count = vcap.get(7)
    
    print('frames count:', frame_count)  # float `frame_count`

    #print('cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH :', cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # 3
    #print('cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT:', cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # 4
    #print('cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS         :', cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)           # 5
    #print('cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT :', cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)   # 7
```

---

**EDIT 2020:** All properties in [How do I get usb webcam property IDs for OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265171/1832058)

Comment: It works fine for my files through CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH/CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, thank you.

Comment: @furas: Is fps 0 for just one video, or for many? If many, are videos from a single source(same camera)?

Comment: @saurabheights I checked and `vcap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)` gives good results for `http stream` and `rtsp stream`, but not for file and camera. `vcap.get(7)` gives good result for file but not for camera and streams. `7` probably means `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`. (doc: [VideoCapture::get](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get))

Comment: @saurabheights I checked only one file - created from some stream using CV.

Comment: @furas: Thanks for reply. Could you tell the opencv version you are using? "print cv2.__version__" - command for it.

Comment: @saurabheights CV2 2.4.8, Python 2.7.12, Linux Mint 17.3 (based on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @furas On Mac, CV: 3.0.0-dev, Py: 2.7.10. it seems to work for an mp4 I tested on, got FPS:- 23.8095238095. Should have been fixed upstream. Thank you for answer. :)

Comment: Note, the `cv2.cv.CV_*` namespace is now obsolute. Just reference `cv2.*` instead.

Comment: @Gulzar you may prefer names instead of numbers in `vcap.get()` but I wanted to show all versions and I put back code which you removed

Comment: @furas Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad . As I see it, most of the people entering this page are not programmers by profession, but rather data scientists or other. Thus will not see the fault in this. Yes, writing like this works, but it leaves the code not readable. The names are there for a reason.

Comment: @furas Furthermore, `I wanted to show all versions` is not valid reasoning: you could add any arbitry number of `width  = vcap.get(3+1-1+1-1)`. Still works, still "a version", obviously not good. I am not trying to be a prick about it, just want people to use the correct form, because no one is going to read our comments.

Comment: there is no real meaning to "`3`", and it isn't really an integer. It is an Enum, and should be treated as such.

Comment: in answer I have also "good version" before "bad version" so everyone can choose which version to use.

Comment: @furas Sorry, I can't see why to let people copy paste a bad practice. I really would like yo know your thoughts about this. Do you think it is a good practice? Do you think there is value in it I don't see? Please explain, I really want to learn.

Answer (score 23):

```
width = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH )
height = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT )
fps =  vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

or

```
width = vcap.get(3)
height = vcap.get(4)
fps = vcap.get(5)
```

Answer (score 11):

For the 3.3.1 version, the methods have changed. Check this link for the changes: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d

Instead of `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` use `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and others as necessary from the link above.

Answer (score 3):

```
cv2.__version__
'3.4.3' 

w = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
h = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
n_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
```

Comment: `fps` shouldn't be casted to `int`: it can have fractions to it. Use `fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

for `ret, frame = cv2.VideoCapture` use `frame.shape` to get Width and Height.

```
height, width, channels = frame.shape
    print(width)
```

Answer (score 1):

For OpenCV `versions = 4.x.x`:

```
    width  = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   
    height = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though solved answers are here, in 2021, it got a little changed. (OpenCV version = `4.5.2`)

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4') #0 for camera


if cap.isOpened(): 
    width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)   # float `width`
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)  # float `height`
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # float `fps`
    total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) # float `total_frame_in_the_video` (should not be applicable for camera)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **vcap.get(i)** method, where *i* can be between 0 and 21, according to the OpenCV [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get).

Answer (score -1):

You can get video width and height with opencv using below code.

```py
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
frameWidth = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
frameHeight = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
```