# How do I get usb webcam property IDs for OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, usb, webcam

I want to lock the focus on my USB webcam I'm using with OpenCV but how do I find the Property ID numbers for that webcam so I can set them.

I used

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
for i in range(64):
        
    print(f'ID {i} = {vid.get(i)}')
```

to get all the values but I don't know which bool value is which.

Driver: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. FULL HD 1080P Webcam
Cam: Nextech Autofocus 1080P HD Webcam

```
ID 0 = 0.0
ID 1 = -1.0
ID 2 = -1.0
ID 3 = 640.0
ID 4 = 480.0
ID 5 = 30.0
ID 6 = 1196444237.0
ID 7 = -1.0
ID 8 = 16.0
ID 9 = 0.0
ID 10 = 0.0
ID 11 = 0.0
ID 12 = 66.0
ID 13 = 0.0
ID 14 = -1.0
ID 15 = 166.0
ID 16 = 1.0
ID 17 = -1.0
ID 18 = -1.0
ID 19 = -1.0
ID 20 = 2.0
ID 21 = 3.0
ID 22 = 165.0
ID 23 = 4600.0
ID 24 = -1.0
ID 25 = -1.0
ID 26 = -1.0
ID 27 = 0.0
ID 28 = 120.0
ID 29 = -1.0
ID 30 = -1.0
ID 31 = -1.0
ID 32 = 0.0
ID 33 = 0.0
ID 34 = 0.0
ID 35 = -1.0
ID 36 = -1.0
ID 37 = -1.0
ID 38 = 4.0
ID 39 = 1.0
ID 40 = -1.0
ID 41 = -1.0
ID 42 = 200.0
ID 43 = -1.0
ID 44 = 1.0
ID 45 = 4600.0
ID 46 = -1.0
ID 47 = -1.0
...
ID 63 = -1.0
```

I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Please specify what operating system you are using.

Comment: these values are somewhere in documentation  and they have also special variables like `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`  - see `print(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)` gives `3` and you can do `vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)`

Comment: see in `cv::VideoCaptureProperties` in documentation for `C/C++` in [Flags for video I/O](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html) - Python uses the same values and similar names - ie. `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` instead of `cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`

Comment: @MichaelGruner I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: I got the manual focus working using cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS thanks @furas but are these numbers the same on every computer? Is there a table of device codes I can reference for a specific webcam or are they universal?

Comment: there are the same on all computer (and the same for Python and C/C++) but I don't if all devices/cams will respect all properties. But I never hear about table for different devices so they should be unversal.

Comment: BTW: see text in previous link in [VideoCaptureProperties](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) - there is `VideoCapture generic properties identifier` - so these properties should be universal for all devices/codes. And there is also link [Additional flags for video I/O API backends](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dfc/group__videoio__flags__others.html) for individual properties for different codecs.

Comment: @furas very helpful thanks. this answers my post. I don't know how this works completely but if you compile that into an answer il mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `C/C++` documentation [Flags for video I/O](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html) in section `enum cv::VideoCaptureProperties` you can find values and names ie.

```
cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH =3,
```

For python it will be

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH = 3
```

what you can check with

```
print(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

---

All values from this page

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC = 0
cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES = 1
cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO = 2
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH = 3
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT = 4
cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS = 5
cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC = 6
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT = 7
cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT = 8
cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE = 9
cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS = 10
cv2.CAP_PROP_CONTRAST = 11
cv2.CAP_PROP_SATURATION = 12
cv2.CAP_PROP_HUE = 13
cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN = 14
cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE = 15
cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB = 16
cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U = 17
cv2.CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION = 18
cv2.CAP_PROP_MONOCHROME = 19
cv2.CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS = 20
cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE = 21
cv2.CAP_PROP_GAMMA = 22
cv2.CAP_PROP_TEMPERATURE = 23
cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER = 24
cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER_DELAY = 25
cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V = 26
cv2.CAP_PROP_ZOOM = 27
cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS = 28
cv2.CAP_PROP_GUID = 29
cv2.CAP_PROP_ISO_SPEED = 30
cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT = 32
cv2.CAP_PROP_PAN = 33
cv2.CAP_PROP_TILT = 34
cv2.CAP_PROP_ROLL = 35
cv2.CAP_PROP_IRIS = 36
cv2.CAP_PROP_SETTINGS = 37
cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE = 38
cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS = 39
cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_NUM = 40
cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_DEN = 41
cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKEND = 42
cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL = 43
cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB = 44
cv2.CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE = 45
cv2.CAP_PROP_CODEC_PIXEL_FORMAT = 46
cv2.CAP_PROP_BITRATE = 47
cv2.CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_META = 48
cv2.CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_AUTO = 49
```

---

On the same page but little lower you can see [VideoCaptureProperties](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) with information

```
VideoCapture generic properties identifier.

Reading / writing properties involves many layers. 
Some unexpected result might happens along this chain. 
Effective behaviour depends from device hardware, driver and API Backend.
```

Which can means that these values are universal for all devices but some of devices or codecs/drivers may not have some values.

There is also link [Additional flags for video I/O API backends](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dfc/group__videoio__flags__others.html) with properties only for some codes/drivers.

---

On page [Video I/O with OpenCV Overview](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) you can also see

```
Each backend supports devices properties (cv::VideoCaptureProperties) in a different way 
or might not support any property at all.
```

---

**BTW:**

Python's names (but without numbers) are also in doc for old version 2.4:
[VideoCapture::get](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get)

---

In much older versions Python was using little different names - ie.

```
cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made program to list all properties sorted by values.

If you skip `sorted()` then you get sorted by names.

```
import cv2

properties = []

for name in dir(cv2):
    if name.startswith('CAP_PROP'):
        value = getattr(cv2, name)
        properties.append((value, name))
        
# it will sort by values
# originally it is sorted by names
properties = sorted(properties)

for value, name in properties:
    print(f' {value:5} | cv2.{name}')
```

Sorted by values:

```
    -4 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_OFF
    -3 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_MANUAL
    -2 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_AUTO
    -1 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_ONE_PUSH_AUTO
     0 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
     1 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES
     2 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO
     3 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
     4 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
     5 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS
     6 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC
     7 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
     8 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT
     9 | cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE
    10 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS
    11 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CONTRAST
    12 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SATURATION
    13 | cv2.CAP_PROP_HUE
    14 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN
    15 | cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE
    16 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB
    17 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U
    18 | cv2.CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION
    19 | cv2.CAP_PROP_MONOCHROME
    20 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS
    21 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE
    22 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GAMMA
    23 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TEMPERATURE
    24 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER
    25 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER_DELAY
    26 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V
    27 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ZOOM
    28 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS
    29 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GUID
    30 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ISO_SPEED
    31 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MAX
    32 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT
    33 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PAN
    34 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TILT
    35 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ROLL
    36 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IRIS
    37 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SETTINGS
    38 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE
    39 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS
    40 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_NUM
    41 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_DEN
    42 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKEND
    43 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL
    44 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB
    45 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE
    46 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CODEC_PIXEL_FORMAT
    47 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BITRATE
   100 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_OUTPUT_MODE
   101 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_FRAME_MAX_DEPTH
   102 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_BASELINE
   103 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_FOCAL_LENGTH
   104 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION
   104 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION_ON
   105 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_APPROX_FRAME_SYNC
   106 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE
   107 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_CIRCLE_BUFFER
   108 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_MAX_TIME_DURATION
   109 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_GENERATOR_PRESENT
   110 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI2_SYNC
   111 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI2_MIRROR
   200 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GSTREAMER_QUEUE_LENGTH
   300 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_MULTICASTIP
   301 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_FRAMESTARTTRIGGERMODE
   302 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_DECIMATIONHORIZONTAL
   303 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_DECIMATIONVERTICAL
   304 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGX
   305 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGY
   306 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_PIXELFORMAT
   400 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DOWNSAMPLING
   401 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DATA_FORMAT
   402 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OFFSET_X
   403 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OFFSET_Y
   404 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SOURCE
   405 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SOFTWARE
   406 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_SELECTOR
   407 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_MODE
   408 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_LEVEL
   409 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPO_SELECTOR
   410 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPO_MODE
   411 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LED_SELECTOR
   412 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LED_MODE
   413 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_MANUAL_WB
   414 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AUTO_WB
   415 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG
   416 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXP_PRIORITY
   417 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AE_MAX_LIMIT
   418 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AG_MAX_LIMIT
   419 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_LEVEL
   420 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TIMEOUT
   421 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXPOSURE
   422 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXPOSURE_BURST_COUNT
   423 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAIN_SELECTOR
   424 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAIN
   426 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DOWNSAMPLING_TYPE
   427 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_SELECTOR
   428 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_VERTICAL
   429 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_HORIZONTAL
   430 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_PATTERN
   431 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_SELECTOR
   432 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_VERTICAL
   433 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_HORIZONTAL
   434 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_PATTERN
   435 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_FORMAT
   436 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SHUTTER_TYPE
   437 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_TAPS
   439 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_OFFSET_X
   440 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_OFFSET_Y
   441 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_WIDTH
   442 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_HEIGHT
   445 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BPC
   448 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KR
   449 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KG
   450 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KB
   451 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WIDTH
   452 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HEIGHT
   459 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LIMIT_BANDWIDTH
   460 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   461 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   462 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   463 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_PACKING
   464 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_PACKING_TYPE
   465 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IS_COOLED
   466 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COOLING
   467 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TARGET_TEMP
   468 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CHIP_TEMP
   469 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HOUS_TEMP
   470 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CMS
   471 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_APPLY_CMS
   474 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_IS_COLOR
   475 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COLOR_FILTER_ARRAY
   476 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAMMAY
   477 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAMMAC
   478 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SHARPNESS
   479 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_00
   480 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_01
   481 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_02
   482 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_03
   483 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_10
   484 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_11
   485 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_12
   486 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_13
   487 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_20
   488 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_21
   489 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_22
   490 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_23
   491 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_30
   492 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_31
   493 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_32
   494 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_33
   495 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEFAULT_CC_MATRIX
   498 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SELECTOR
   499 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_FRAME_BURST_COUNT
   507 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_EN
   508 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_T0
   509 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_T1
   510 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_POL
   511 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_MODE
   512 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_APERTURE_VALUE
   513 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_MOVEMENT_VALUE
   514 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_MOVE
   515 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE
   516 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH
   517 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FEATURE_SELECTOR
   518 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FEATURE
   521 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_MODEL_ID
   522 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_SN
   529 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_FORMAT_RGB32_ALPHA
   530 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_PAYLOAD_SIZE
   531 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRANSPORT_PIXEL_FORMAT
   532 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ
   533 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_CLOCK_FREQ_INDEX
   534 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_OUTPUT_CHANNEL_COUNT
   535 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FRAMERATE
   536 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COUNTER_SELECTOR
   537 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COUNTER_VALUE
   538 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TIMING_MODE
   539 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AVAILABLE_BANDWIDTH
   540 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BUFFER_POLICY
   541 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_EN
   542 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_INDEX
   543 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_VALUE
   544 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_DELAY
   545 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TS_RST_MODE
   546 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TS_RST_SOURCE
   547 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IS_DEVICE_EXIST
   548 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_BUFFER_SIZE
   549 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_BUFFER_SIZE_UNIT
   550 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TRANSPORT_BUFFER_SIZE
   551 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BUFFERS_QUEUE_SIZE
   552 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TRANSPORT_BUFFER_COMMIT
   553 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_RECENT_FRAME
   554 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_RESET
   555 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COLUMN_FPN_CORRECTION
   558 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_MODE
   559 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR
   560 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_KNEEPOINT_COUNT
   561 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_T1
   562 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_T2
   563 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_KNEEPOINT1
   564 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_KNEEPOINT2
   565 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_BLACK_LEVEL
   571 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HW_REVISION
   572 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBUG_LEVEL
   573 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AUTO_BANDWIDTH_CALCULATION
   580 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_FILE_SIZE
   581 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FREE_FFS_SIZE
   582 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_USED_FFS_SIZE
   583 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_ACCESS_KEY
   585 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_FEATURE_SELECTOR
   586 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_FEATURE_VALUE
   587 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TEST_PATTERN_GENERATOR_SELECTOR
   588 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TEST_PATTERN
   589 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_REGION_SELECTOR
   590 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HOUS_BACK_SIDE_TEMP
   591 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ROW_FPN_CORRECTION
   594 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_FILE_ID
   595 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_REGION_MODE
   596 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_BOARD_TEMP
   600 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ARAVIS_AUTOTRIGGER
  9001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FOCUS
  9002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_EXPOSURE
  9003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FLASH
  9004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_WHITEBALANCE
  9005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_TORCH
 10001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_OFFSET_X
 10002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_OFFSET_Y
 10003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_WIDTH_MAX
 10004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_HEIGH_MAX
 10005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_SENS_WIDTH
 10006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_SENS_HEIGH
 11001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_PROFILE_COUNT
 11002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_PROFILE_IDX
 11003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_LOW_CONFIDENCE_VALUE
 11004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_SATURATION_VALUE
 11005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD
 11006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH_HORZ
 11007 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH_VERT
 17001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_PREVIEW
 17002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_WIDGET_ENUMERATE
 17003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_RELOAD_CONFIG
 17004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_RELOAD_ON_CHANGE
 17005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_COLLECT_MSGS
 17006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_FLUSH_MSGS
 17007 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SPEED
 17008 | cv2.CAP_PROP_APERTURE
 17009 | cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSUREPROGRAM
 17010 | cv2.CAP_PROP_VIEWFINDER
 18000 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IMAGES_BASE
 19000 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IMAGES_LAST
```

Sorted by names:

```
 17008 | cv2.CAP_PROP_APERTURE
   600 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ARAVIS_AUTOTRIGGER
    39 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS
    21 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE
    44 | cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTO_WB
    42 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKEND
    32 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT
    47 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BITRATE
    10 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS
    38 | cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE
    43 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CHANNEL
    46 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CODEC_PIXEL_FORMAT
    11 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CONTRAST
    16 | cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB
    31 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MAX
    -2 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_AUTO
    -3 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_MANUAL
    -1 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_ONE_PUSH_AUTO
    -4 | cv2.CAP_PROP_DC1394_OFF
    15 | cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE
 17009 | cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSUREPROGRAM
    28 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS
     8 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT
     6 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC
     5 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS
     7 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
     4 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
     3 | cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
    14 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN
    22 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GAMMA
 10004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_HEIGH_MAX
 10001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_OFFSET_X
 10002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_OFFSET_Y
 10006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_SENS_HEIGH
 10005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_SENS_WIDTH
 10003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GIGA_FRAME_WIDTH_MAX
 17005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_COLLECT_MSGS
 17006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_FLUSH_MSGS
 17001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_PREVIEW
 17003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_RELOAD_CONFIG
 17004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_RELOAD_ON_CHANGE
 17002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GPHOTO2_WIDGET_ENUMERATE
   200 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GSTREAMER_QUEUE_LENGTH
    29 | cv2.CAP_PROP_GUID
    13 | cv2.CAP_PROP_HUE
 18000 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IMAGES_BASE
 19000 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IMAGES_LAST
 11005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD
 11006 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH_HORZ
 11007 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH_VERT
 11003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_LOW_CONFIDENCE_VALUE
 11004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_DEPTH_SATURATION_VALUE
 11001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_PROFILE_COUNT
 11002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_INTELPERC_PROFILE_IDX
  9002 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_EXPOSURE
  9003 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FLASH
  9001 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_FOCUS
  9005 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_TORCH
  9004 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IOS_DEVICE_WHITEBALANCE
    36 | cv2.CAP_PROP_IRIS
    30 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ISO_SPEED
     9 | cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE
    19 | cv2.CAP_PROP_MONOCHROME
   111 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI2_MIRROR
   110 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI2_SYNC
   105 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_APPROX_FRAME_SYNC
   102 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_BASELINE
   107 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_CIRCLE_BUFFER
   103 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_FOCAL_LENGTH
   101 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_FRAME_MAX_DEPTH
   109 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_GENERATOR_PRESENT
   106 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE
   108 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_MAX_TIME_DURATION
   100 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_OUTPUT_MODE
   104 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION
   104 | cv2.CAP_PROP_OPENNI_REGISTRATION_ON
    33 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PAN
     2 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO
     1 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES
     0 | cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
   304 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGX
   305 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_BINNINGY
   302 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_DECIMATIONHORIZONTAL
   303 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_DECIMATIONVERTICAL
   301 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_FRAMESTARTTRIGGERMODE
   300 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_MULTICASTIP
   306 | cv2.CAP_PROP_PVAPI_PIXELFORMAT
    18 | cv2.CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION
    35 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ROLL
    41 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_DEN
    40 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SAR_NUM
    12 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SATURATION
    37 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SETTINGS
    20 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS
 17007 | cv2.CAP_PROP_SPEED
    23 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TEMPERATURE
    34 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TILT
    24 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER
    25 | cv2.CAP_PROP_TRIGGER_DELAY
 17010 | cv2.CAP_PROP_VIEWFINDER
    45 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WB_TEMPERATURE
    17 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U
    26 | cv2.CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V
   548 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_BUFFER_SIZE
   549 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_BUFFER_SIZE_UNIT
   499 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_FRAME_BURST_COUNT
   538 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TIMING_MODE
   552 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TRANSPORT_BUFFER_COMMIT
   550 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ACQ_TRANSPORT_BUFFER_SIZE
   415 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG
   419 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_LEVEL
   442 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_HEIGHT
   439 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_OFFSET_X
   440 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_OFFSET_Y
   441 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AEAG_ROI_WIDTH
   417 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AE_MAX_LIMIT
   418 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AG_MAX_LIMIT
   471 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_APPLY_CMS
   573 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AUTO_BANDWIDTH_CALCULATION
   414 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AUTO_WB
   539 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_AVAILABLE_BANDWIDTH
   429 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_HORIZONTAL
   430 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_PATTERN
   427 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_SELECTOR
   428 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BINNING_VERTICAL
   445 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BPC
   551 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BUFFERS_QUEUE_SIZE
   540 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_BUFFER_POLICY
   479 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_00
   480 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_01
   481 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_02
   482 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_03
   483 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_10
   484 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_11
   485 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_12
   486 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_13
   487 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_20
   488 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_21
   489 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_22
   490 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_23
   491 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_30
   492 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_31
   493 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_32
   494 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CC_MATRIX_33
   468 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CHIP_TEMP
   470 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_CMS
   475 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COLOR_FILTER_ARRAY
   555 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COLUMN_FPN_CORRECTION
   466 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COOLING
   536 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COUNTER_SELECTOR
   537 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_COUNTER_VALUE
   401 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DATA_FORMAT
   507 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_EN
   510 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_POL
   508 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_T0
   509 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBOUNCE_T1
   572 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEBUG_LEVEL
   433 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_HORIZONTAL
   434 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_PATTERN
   431 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_SELECTOR
   432 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DECIMATION_VERTICAL
   495 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEFAULT_CC_MATRIX
   521 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_MODEL_ID
   554 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_RESET
   522 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DEVICE_SN
   400 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DOWNSAMPLING
   426 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_DOWNSAMPLING_TYPE
   421 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXPOSURE
   422 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXPOSURE_BURST_COUNT
   416 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_EXP_PRIORITY
   583 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_ACCESS_KEY
   594 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_FILE_ID
   580 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FFS_FILE_SIZE
   535 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FRAMERATE
   581 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_FREE_FFS_SIZE
   424 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAIN
   423 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAIN_SELECTOR
   477 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAMMAC
   476 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GAMMAY
   408 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_LEVEL
   407 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_MODE
   406 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPI_SELECTOR
   410 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPO_MODE
   409 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_GPO_SELECTOR
   559 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR
   560 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_KNEEPOINT_COUNT
   561 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_T1
   562 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HDR_T2
   452 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HEIGHT
   590 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HOUS_BACK_SIDE_TEMP
   469 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HOUS_TEMP
   571 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_HW_REVISION
   565 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_BLACK_LEVEL
   462 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   435 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_FORMAT
   529 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_DATA_FORMAT_RGB32_ALPHA
   474 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_IS_COLOR
   530 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IMAGE_PAYLOAD_SIZE
   465 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IS_COOLED
   547 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_IS_DEVICE_EXIST
   563 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_KNEEPOINT1
   564 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_KNEEPOINT2
   412 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LED_MODE
   411 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LED_SELECTOR
   512 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_APERTURE_VALUE
   518 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FEATURE
   517 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FEATURE_SELECTOR
   516 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCAL_LENGTH
   515 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE
   514 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_MOVE
   513 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_FOCUS_MOVEMENT_VALUE
   511 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LENS_MODE
   459 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LIMIT_BANDWIDTH
   541 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_EN
   542 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_INDEX
   543 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_LUT_VALUE
   413 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_MANUAL_WB
   402 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OFFSET_X
   403 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OFFSET_Y
   461 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   463 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_PACKING
   464 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_OUTPUT_DATA_PACKING_TYPE
   553 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_RECENT_FRAME
   595 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_REGION_MODE
   589 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_REGION_SELECTOR
   591 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_ROW_FPN_CORRECTION
   596 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_BOARD_TEMP
   532 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ
   533 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_CLOCK_FREQ_INDEX
   460 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_DATA_BIT_DEPTH
   585 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_FEATURE_SELECTOR
   586 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_FEATURE_VALUE
   558 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_MODE
   534 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_OUTPUT_CHANNEL_COUNT
   437 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SENSOR_TAPS
   478 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SHARPNESS
   436 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_SHUTTER_TYPE
   467 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TARGET_TEMP
   588 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TEST_PATTERN
   587 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TEST_PATTERN_GENERATOR_SELECTOR
   420 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TIMEOUT
   531 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRANSPORT_PIXEL_FORMAT
   544 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_DELAY
   498 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SELECTOR
   405 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SOFTWARE
   404 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TRG_SOURCE
   545 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TS_RST_MODE
   546 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_TS_RST_SOURCE
   582 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_USED_FFS_SIZE
   450 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KB
   449 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KG
   448 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KR
   451 | cv2.CAP_PROP_XI_WIDTH
    27 | cv2.CAP_PROP_ZOOM
```