# Videocapture() with multiple cameras

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera, port

I have 3 identical cameras running in my system, the only difference between them is the USB port where are plugged. I need to load a specific Python script using OpenCV for each camera, and my code is as simple as:

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
```

where index equals to 0, 1, 2 respectively in each script. The problem comes when I restart my PC and run the same code, sometimes runs as expected and sometimes 1 or 2 cameras had switched their index (not changing any code or unplugging from USB) so the result is loading the script without the corresponding camera.

For example, if in script2.py the camera index defined was 2, then I restart the PC, and now when running script2.py loads the camera with index 0.

Any solutions for this? How can I specify the physical port to VideoCapture() to be always the same? I'm running Win10

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [Create openCV VideoCapture from interface name instead of camera numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821763/create-opencv-videocapture-from-interface-name-instead-of-camera-numbers)

Comment: This was pretty usefull, but im running my code on Windows so i need to reach the same usb location on my machine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [How to check available webcams from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348838/how-to-check-available-webcams-from-the-command-line#answer-1124192) suggests a Python library. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but even with that library i can't get an unique identifier for each camera, just the name which in my case i have 3 cameras named "H264 USB Camera", so my systems keeps loading them wrong sometimes.

Comment: Did you look at [OpenCV with multiple webcams - how to tell which camera is which in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962748/opencv-with-multiple-webcams-how-to-tell-which-camera-is-which-in-code)

Comment: for C++ and windows OS you could have a look at https://github.com/studiosi/OpenCVDeviceEnumerator (maybe you can write a Python Wrapper?). For Linux you can probably find some video 4 linux tools. BUT depending on your camera type, it might be possible that there are no serial numbers or similar availbale. However, it is probably somehow possible to find out to which hardware port a device is connected?!?

Comment: @Ahx The answer is for Ubuntu in your link. But there is mentioned [OpenCV VideoCapture device index / device number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298588/opencv-videocapture-device-index-device-number/41299177) which seems to have the solutions for Windows in [CV-camera-finder](https://github.com/pvys/CV-camera-finder).

Comment: @Micka I found the physical USB port where each camera is connected, the problem is that i cannot use that value in VideoCapture

Comment: opencv uses directShow in windows, so you'll need a way to find directShow device numbers and usn information combined.

Comment: did you have a look at: https://github.com/studiosi/OpenCVDeviceEnumerator ? there is a devicePath variable for each device, and the id. Maybe this is what you need. Not Python unfortunately, but after testing that this devicePath is what you need you might be able to search for identical Python functions.

Comment: I think this can be achieved using https://github.com/andreaschiavinato/python_grabber , look at the [first example](https://github.com/andreaschiavinato/python_grabber/blob/master/examples/example_1.py). You would need to know the monikers of each camera though.

Comment: Are the three cameras running with default configs and are they different? If so, you can check by getting their attributes like exposure etc using cap.get(). something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256300/how-do-i-get-usb-webcam-property-ids-for-opencv

Comment: Hi guys, at the time of today i haven't resolved this issue, let me explain my iterations and results:
1 - Just selecting the index for each camera -> After every restart the index may have been changed or maybe not
2 - I used DevCon to extract the hardware ID of the cameras for disabling all of them with the purpose of enabling again 1 by 1 and expecting the new index come in the right order -> The index still the same
3 - I made a custom PCB which has 3 relay for switing on/off the power of the cameras to again, powering them in order before use in script -> Still not work
Im desperated.

Comment: Did you try all the mentioned GitHub projects? It would be nice if you could list the results  of each of them. I suggest creating an answer and listing the important steps so that you can get more help and find solutions to specific cases.

Comment: @Burak Yep i checked them all again just for refreshing and i got some interesting aproach but not completly fine for me. In your  previous answer you posted a link to the Camera Finder, and my results were those:
It works great, however in my case i got 3 cameras with the same name and i cant recognise them programatically cause all 3 are "HD USB Camera". I tried to change its "friendlyName" property from the windows register to "CAM 1" but cameraFinder always return HD USB Camera. Any help would be extremly apreciated :)

Comment: This question attracted the most viewers I've ever seen for an unsolved good question. If none of the proposed methods works, the best you can do is to find a workaround. For example, put different colored small papers in front of each camera and distinguish them by computer vision before the rest of the script. Or an easier solution, switch to Ubuntu :) Good luck!

Comment: Well guys, i haven't reached my goal to resolve this issue in a nice and plain way as it supposed to be but i've done a workaround using image analysis detecting the environment for each camera. Despite the fact it works well it seems ridiculous to me not having any opencv function to solve this issue, because this shouldn't be a problem, its just selecting a camera. Thanks a lot for your help guys.